# In (SAMSUNG J7 Core) after I installed the last Software update and run my application, returning <unknown ssid> error occur

Tags: java, android, samsung-mobile

In my app I have to get the connected wifi ssid. **Before I update latest software in my test device (SAMSUNG J7 core) android version 8.1.0**, the following code works and **returns the connected wifi ssid** when I call getConnectedWifiSSID().

But **after I update latest software in my device (SAMSUNG J7 core)**, when I call getConnectedWifiSSID() it **returns unknown SSID** . Please give me some suggestions. How should I solve this issue?

**I get wifi ssid with the following code and it's work before I update latest software in (SAMSUNG J7 core) android version 8.1.0.**

```
 public String getConnectedWifiSSID() {
        WifiInfo wifiInfo = (WifiInfo) wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
        try {
            return formatSSID(wifiInfo.getSSID());
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
```

**I already apply this permissions in AndroidManifest.xml.**

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

**I also already asked the user for ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission.**

```
      Dexter.withActivity(this)
            .withPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            .withListener(new PermissionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPermissionGranted(PermissionGrantedResponse response) {
                    setUpFirebaseRemoteConfig();
                }

                @Override
                public void onPermissionDenied(PermissionDeniedResponse response) {
                    finish();
                }

                @Override
                public void onPermissionRationaleShouldBeShown(PermissionRequest permission, PermissionToken token) {
                    token.continuePermissionRequest();
                }
            }).check();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution for this issue.

Before updating firmware in SAMSUNG J7 core, we can get connected wifi name programmatically.
But after updated firmware in SAMSUNG J7 core, when we try to get connected wifi name programmatically it returns .   So, bug no. 2342 occurs.

This issue can be solved by enabling GPS on the device. (User need to enable GPS) When the device GPS is enable, we can get connected wifi name programmatically. If GPS off, getting wifi name returns .

Retrieving the SSID requires location services to be enabled on the device. In some latest farmware versions and android version 9.0.

https://developer.android.com/about/versions/pie/android-9.0-changes-all